# Pandas right align columns with numbers after to_html()

Tags: python, css, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to export to HTML using the `to_html()` method. Is there a way this can be achieved with the `formatters` or `float_format` parameter? How would this look like? Could I create a function that checks if a column contains numbers only and then assign a certain class to it that can then be linked to a css style? Note that I only want columns with numbers only to be right-aligned. All other columns should note be affected. Also, the headers should all be left-aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp will replace the tag of cells containing a float or int.
Afterwards, you should add the relevant style to your page.

```
import re    
re.sub(r"<td>((\d)+?(.(\d)+))", r"<td class='my_class'>\1", df.to_html())
```

Comment: This works great except for items like numbers like 10%. It works for 100% but not for numbers from 1%-99%. Any suggestions how I can include percentage? thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific, do you mean you could have "100" "100.10" et aussi "1%" "10.1%" ... etc ? If this is the case  ```<td>((\d)+?(.(\d)+)?%)```